# How I must update view in Android app?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development and I need some help.

I have an Android App that has a text editor and a button to send the text. When the button is clicked I have to do some requests to a web server and show a downloaded image and some text below the text editor. While this operation is in process, I want to show a progress bar or something similar.

I think I must use an `AsyncTask` to perform the web server operations, but I am not clear what solution to use to refresh the view with the data obtained:

- Use a ViewStud
- Use Fragments
- Use a hidden view, update it and then show it.

Can anyone help me on how it might proceed?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: What you have done till now,please paste your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your requirements can be achieved using AsyncTask. Please prefer to [AsyncTask document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for further information.

In order to  refresh the view with the data obtained, you can you onPostExecute method. Something along this line:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Trailer> trailer) {
        Log.d(TAG,"ONPOSTEXECUTED");
        trailerList.clear();
        for (Trailer t:trailer) {
         trailerList.add(t);
        }
        mMovie.setTrailer(trailerList);
        updateTrailerListView();
    }
```

Where:

```
    private void updateTrailerListView() {
    LinearLayout trailerlayout=(LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_trailer);
    // empty the list view of trailers. This is used to prevent duplicating listview
    trailerlayout.removeAllViews();
    if (!trailerList.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < trailerList.size(); i++) {
            // Inflate the trailer layout and add the textview to the linear layout
            View v=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.trailer_layout,null);
            TextView textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.trailer_layout_textView);
            final Trailer t = trailerList.get(i);
            // Set the name of the trailer
            textView.setText(t.getName());

            // Set onclick listener to the View to open the trailer in Youtube or other native app
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            // URI of the youtube link
                            Uri.parse("http://youtube.com/watch?v=" + t.getKey()));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            trailerlayout.addView(v);
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"update trailer List View");
    }
}
```

This is one of many examples of using onPostExecute to update view. You can write your own updateView() method depends on your needs.

As for updating progress, search onProgressUpdate method and how to implement them in the official document.